# In Perl, how do you pack a hash and unpack it back to its original state?

Tags: json, perl, hash, pack

I want to save a hash as a packed string in a db, I get the pack part down ok, but I'm having a problem getting the hash back

test hash

```
my $hash = {

   test_string   => 'apples,bananas,oranges',
   test_subhash  => { like => 'apples' },
   test_subarray => [ red, yellow, orange ]

}
```

I thought maybe I could use JSON:XS like in [this example](http://martin-evans.me.uk/node/42) to convert the hash to a json string, and then packing the JSON string...

Thoughts on this approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Storable](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Storable) is capable of storing Perl structures very precisely. If you need to remember that something is a weak reference, etc, you want Storable. Otherwise, I'd avoid it.

JSON ([Cpanel::JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Cpanel::JSON::XS)) and YAML are good choices.

- You can have problems if you store something using one version of Storable and try to retrieve it using an earlier version. That means all machines that access the database must have the same version of Storable.
- Cpanel::JSON::XS is faster than Storable.
- A fast YAML module is probably faster than Storable.
- JSON can't store objects, but YAML and Storable can.
- JSON and YAML are human readable (well, for some humans).
- JSON and YAML are easy to parse and generate in other languages.

Usage:

```
my $for_the_db = encode_json($hash);
my $hash = decode_json($from_the_db);
```

I don't know what you mean by "packing". The string produces by Cpanel::JSON::XS's `encode_json` can be stored as-is into a `BLOB` field, while the string produced by `Cpanel::JSON::XS->new->encode` can be stored as-is into a `TEXT` field.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to give the  [`Storable`](https://metacpan.org/module/Storable) module a whirl.

It can :

- store your hash(ref) as a string with `freeze`
- `thaw` it out at the time of retrieval

Comment: `freeze` returns bytes, not characters, even if you freeze something that contains UTF-8 characters.

Comment: @cjm : Thanks for pointing that out... I misread the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of different ways to store a data structure in a scalar and then "restore" it back to it's original state. There are advantages and disadvantages to each.

Since you started with JSON, I'll show you can example using it.

```
use JSON;
my $hash = {

   test_string   => 'apples,bananas,oranges',
   test_subhash  => { like => 'apples' },
   test_subarray => [ red, yellow, orange ]

}

my $stored = encode_json($hash);

my $restored = decode_json($stored);
```

Storable, as was already suggested, is also a good idea. But it can be rather quirky. It's great if you just want your own script/system to store and restore the data, but beyond that, it can be a pain in the butt. Even transferring data across different operating systems can cause problems. It was recommended that you use freeze, and for most local applications, that's the right call. If you decide to use Storable for sending data across multiple machines, look at using nfreeze instead.

That being said, there are a ton of encoding methods that can handle "storing" data structures. Look at YAML or XML.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "convert the hash to a JSON string, and then packing the JSON string".  What further "packing" is required?  Or did you mean "storing"?

There's a number of alternative methods for storing hashes in a database.

As Zaid suggested, you can use [Storable](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Storable) to `freeze` and `thaw` your hash.  This is likely to be the fastest method (although you should benchmark with the data you're using if speed is critical).  But Storable uses a binary format which is not human readable, which means that you will only be able to access this field using Perl.

As you suggested, you can store the hash as a JSON string.  JSON has the advantage of being fairly human readable, and there are JSON libraries for most any language, making it easy to access your database field from something other than Perl.

You can also switch to a document-oriented database like [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) or [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/), but that's a much bigger step.

Comment: Storable is not the fastest. It stores a lot of info others don't, and that takes time.